# Ivanhoe ladies with wooden rims, wooden rear fender, wooden chain guard

Tags: identify-this-bike

Attic find, any thought as to age, options not on a stock bike, value range.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is a fairly strong rule that we don't do valuations here.  But this bike is a true antique and valuable intellectually if not in raw dollars.  Please resist any temptation to "clean it up" until you have had a chance to have it evaluated by an expert.

Comment: Appears to be ca 1900: https://books.google.com/books?id=B0NhAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=ivanhoe+%22indiana+bicycle%22&source=bl&ots=WZoCE4u6Az&sig=ACfU3U3wHqrJrww1QkVE8bof6ef7aB4wwQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZjePusfvgAhVzMX0KHdjcDDAQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=ivanhoe%20%22indiana%20bicycle%22&f=false

Comment: I'll note that searching suggests that "Ivanhoe" was a brand from a company in Ohio until about 1896, then presumably was taken over by the Indiana company.  And "Ivanhoe" is now apparently an Australian brand of ladies bike, with "retro" styling remarkably similar to the above (though I also find the name used for a bike from Toronto, apparently ca 1917).

Comment: Do you intend on riding it?  I'd be incredibly careful to check of all wooden bits before putting any weight on it.  Its really a museum piece or a display piece - I'd recommend not riding it.   Sweet looking bike though.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect that any attempt to make it rideable would cause fatal damage to the wood parts.  And you'll never find tires for it, anyway.

Comment: According to 'The Wheelmen' website Indiana Bicycle Company manufactured various brand names from 1891-1899. I have forwarded the badge pic and others pics to them for info., thanks for help and thoughts.

Comment: Look at the chain! It has the latest tech from 2019 SRAM Red: Flat outer edge.

Comment: @gschenk good spotting - whats old is new again, eventually.

Comment: She's a beaut! Would love to see in a museum one day.

Comment: @gschenk Exactly what I thought when I first saw the pictures! Wow!

Answer (score 3):

It's an Ivanhoe ladies bike made by the Indiana Bicycle Company between 1898 and 1900.
The company was founded by Albert Augustus Pope in 1898 and changed to the [American Bicycle Company in 1900](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope-Waverley#:%7E:text=The%20company%20was%20originally%20formed%20as%20the%20Indiana,they%20became%20independent%20again%20as%20the%20Waverley%20Company.)

Yours might be the ladies version of the Ivanhoe Special.
Check below the head badge and see if the lower badge use to be there
[image]
[thread from The Cabe](https://thecabe.com/forum/threads/3-1890s-ladies-projects-hudson-ivanhoe-special-waverley.165667/)

The Indiana Bicycle Company also made the Waverly Belle which bears a strong resemblance to the Ivanhoe.
[image]
[bicyclearts.com](http://www.bicyclearts.com/bicycles.php)